# org.hibernate.MappingException - composite id

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my Spring boot - JPA application, I am trying to implement composite key :

```
@Entity
public class User 
{
    @Id
    private String timeStamp;
    @Id
    private String firstName;
    @Id
    private String lastName;
}
```

This gives me error, saying :

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Composite-id class must implement Serializable: com.mua.testkeys.model.User
```

Even if I implement `Serializable` it gives me error.

How can I resolve this ?

Used : Spring + JPA + H2

Comment: Please add what error you are getting after you made it `Serializable`. Also you seem to miss some annotation, like  `@IdClass` or `@EmbeddedId` depending on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Not sure but use '@IdClass' or '@EmbadedId' annotation with your class and be confirm that you follow the rule like, no-args constructor, equles() and hashcode() method serializable, public access modifier used with your customize entity class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Composite Key can be created with `@IdClass` as below.
**User.class**

```
@IdClass(UserPK.class)
@Table(name = "user")
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private String timeStamp;
    @Id
    private String firstName;
    @Id
    private String lastName;
//remaining fields
// getters and setters
}
```

**UserPK.class**

```
public class UserPK {
    private String timeStamp;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
// constructors
// getters and setters
//implement euquels() and hashcode()
}
```

1. Define a Class for primary key with all keys as fields.
2. Implement `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods.
3. Annotate User class with `@IdClass(UserPK.class)`
4. Declare Id fields with `@Id` annotation